# Can an event instance field member be null (assuming it is not forcefully set to null)?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

Suppose I have this as a member of a class:

```
public event EventHandler<MyObject> SomeEventThing;
```

to avoid a nullable reference warning, I have to write:

```
public event EventHandler<MyObject>? SomeEventThing;
```

Does this mean the event field could be null and I've been playing with fire the entire time? Or is this an analyzer bug?

Comment: Shouln't a non-nullable reference type be initialized at declaration?

Comment: It would be helpful if your title and your question sort of had the same answer. Right now I read the title "Is an event field guaranteed to be non-null", and then the first answer starts with "Yes". It's like "Yes, we have no bananas". Can you make your question and its title have the same type of answer, either both yes or both no?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen If you think the answer to a question doesn't follow with the title, responding to the writer of the answer rather than the question writer is the better choice since I have no control over how people answer my questions (or even better yet, edit their answer). Regardless, I updated the title to satisfy your request which hopefully makes the title better overall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a field-like event can absolutely be null - and will be if there are no subscribers to the event. The compiler is correct. The generated event code is backed by a field of the delegate type, and the default value of the field is still null like other reference type fields.

Note that with the null-conditional `?.` operator, it's easy to conditionally invoke the event handlers:

```
SomeEventThing?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs<MyObject>());
```

Comment: Also note that EventHandlers are immutable; every time the subscribers are updated an entirely new list is created.